# Using a loop to get all tables within a database

Tags: php, mysql

> Please understand that I am fairly new to PhP and I might have come by the answer to my question without knowing it. If this is the case, please direct me to the correct answer.

I have a database which has multiple tables in it. Each table does have the exact same structure, as each table corresponds with a different unit within a franchise of restaurants. I am trying to create a "master" page for the franchise owner to be able to pull up all (or one) of the tables onto one page in order to view the data associated with each unit. I have tried every permeation that I could think of to get the code to work right but I keep getting errors thrown at me. The most recent error message that I am getting is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

In past questions people have tried telling me that my code needs to be one way because I only include a portion of my code. This time I will include all of the code within the page that is throwing the errors.

```
<?php
require_once('../dbconnection.php');

$tables = array($_POST["spenard"], $_POST["benson"], $_POST["eagle"],
$_POST["wasilla"], $_POST["boniface"], $_POST["dimond"], $_POST["tudor"],
$_POST["huffman"], $_POST["dtown"], $_POST["airport"], $_POST["college"],
$_POST["npole"], $_POST["kenai"], $_POST["suldotna"]);
$length = count($tables);


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Food Safety Checklist Master List</title>

<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>

<!--<table>
    ?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {?>
        <tr>
            <th>?php echo $tables[$i]; ?></th>
        </tr>
        ?php }
    ?>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>-->

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Food Safety Checklist</th>
    </tr>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
        $query_lists = "SELECT * FROM $tables[$i]";
        $lists = mysqli_query($conn, $query_lists) or
die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $row_lists = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lists);
        $totalRows_lists = mysqli_num_rows($lists);?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row_lists[' ']; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The code for the initiating page is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Food Safety Checklist Master Selection</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <h1>Pizza Hut Food Safety</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <div>
        <form action="mastershow.php" method="post" name="masterselect" id="masterselect">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><h2>Stores</h2></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Run" id="submit" name="submit"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="spenard">Spenard 010576</label></td>
                    <td><input name="spenard" id="spenard" type="checkbox" value="`010576`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td><label for="benson">Benson 011169</label></td>
                    <td><input name="benson" id="benson" type="checkbox" value="`011169`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="eagle">Eagle River 008181</label></td>
                    <td><input name="eagle" id="eagle" type="checkbox" value="`008181`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="wasilla">Wasilla 010324</label></td>
                    <td><input name="wasilla" id="wasilla" type="checkbox" value="`010324`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="boniface">Boniface 008615</label></td>
                    <td><input name="boniface" id="boniface" type="checkbox" value="`008615`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="dimond">W. Dimond 009150</label></td>
                    <td><input name="dimond" id="dimond" type="checkbox" value="`009150`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="tudor">Tudor 014640</label></td>
                    <td><input name="tudor" id="tudor" type="checkbox" value="`014640`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="huffman">Huffman 0101684</label></td>
                    <td><input name="huffman" id="huffma" type="checkbox" value="`010684`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="dtown">6TH AVE 011168</label></td>
                    <td><input name="dtown" id="dtwon" type="checkbox" value="`011168`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="airport">Airport Rd. 014215</label></td>
                    <td><input name="airport" id="airport" type="checkbox" value="`014215`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="college">College Rd. 008179</label></td>
                    <td><input name="college" id="college" type="checkbox" value="`008179`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="npole">North Pole 008339</label></td>
                    <td><input name="npole" id="npole" type="checkbox" value="`008339`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="kenai">Kenai 008668</label></td>
                    <td><input name="kenai" id="kenai" type="checkbox" value="`008668`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="suldotna">Suldotna 031574</label></td>
                    <td><input name="suldotna" id="suldotna" type="checkbox" value="`031574`"><br/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<footer>
    Designed by Greg Weiland &copy;2017
</footer>   

</body>
</html>
```

Again, I am trying to have it to where the franchise owner can "check" which stores to run the report on, and then be able to get all rows from the corresponding tables (again, each table has a name which corresponds to one of the unit numbers) that he has selected. Each table has identical structure. Thank you for any and all help

Comment: I'm just going to throw out there that you may want to adjust your schema. If you create a new table for each franchise, it defeats the dynamic abilities of a relational database. Instead, have a single table that includes a field for franchise (or a primary key to another franchise table). With everything in one table it will be very easy to query the entire thing and you won't have to go back and change your code when you add more franchises in the future.

Comment: @jordan The issue with this is that each unit within the franchise is posting data to the database through another page. I need to be able to pull the data for each "store" individually or all together

Comment: That's totally fine. It should all definitely still be in one table. You can run a query like `SELECT * from example_table WHERE franchise = 'benson'` to get data for a single franchise. You are really setting yourself up for a world of hurt if you use separate tables.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had thought that that was my problem at one point in time so I did set up a table for all entries to be placed in. However, now when I try to call the line with the variable `$tables[$i]` it tells me that there is another error. This is starting to get a little frustrating.

Comment: when I make the sql query `"... WHERE store_number = `$tables[$i]`"` it tells me "Unknown column '' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Do you have a column called store_number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139669/discussion-between-dragonman86-and-jordan-s).

Comment: I'd like to add that Jordan S here is on to something big, so I hope you can avoid going any farther down this road. A relational database designed with relational principles in mind is a pleasure to work with, and if you go the opposite road it is nothing but suffering and agony for eternity.

Answer (score 0):

it tells you that your query is wrong and it is you have a variable inside without telling it that it is a variable fix it like this

```
$query_lists = "SELECT * FROM '$tables[$i]'";
```

edit change this because of the type array

```
  //see my last comment on why i do it this way
  <?php foreach ($tables as $qtables) { 
            mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
            $query_lists = "SELECT * FROM '$qtables'";
```

Comment: This gave me an identical error, only with one of the check box values in it as well. The values of the check boxes all have backticks within the value

Comment: sorry i didn't  see the array type is like this (1,2,3,4,5) the query with [I$] is for this type array with a index  (qtable:,1,qtable:,2,qtable:3) i know if you vardump it doesn't look like this but this the concept, i will edit my answer

Comment: @tadman in "query " you have to use 'variable' please tell me whats wrong with that?

Answer (score -1):

try this instead :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tables[$i];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

then for example youre looking for id within your selection, then just find it with $results['id'];

also a little sidenote : i like putting my database query methods in a seperate php file that i import. in that case, i gather all my data in a $results array and return the array.

something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tables[$i];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$results = array();  
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
return $results;
```